# Swagger (C#) not adding Authorize header

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to get Swagger working with a client credentials flow.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SchemaFilter<SchemaFilter>();

    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "The API", Version = "v1" });

    var basePath = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
    string docFileName = Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.xml").First();
    var docFile = Path.Combine(basePath, docFileName);

    if (File.Exists(docFile))
    {
        c.IncludeXmlComments(docFile);
    }

    // Makes the UI appear and be able to get a token.
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Description = "Bearer token",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("http://www.localhost:5000/connect/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("http://www.localhost:5000/connect/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "thescope", "The scope" } }
            }
        }
    });

    // Docs claim this is necessary; doesn't say what it does in addition to the above.
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                },
                Scheme = "Bearer", // https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },

            new List<string>()
        }
    });
```

On the Swagger web page an *Authorize* button appears and I can use the `client_id` and `client_secret` to get a token.

However, Swagger does not use the token. No `Authorize` header is added to any requests. Why?

Comment: Shot from the hip - but shouldn't the OpenApiReference Id match the security definition name?

Comment: So _security definition name_ is the first parameter to `AddSecurityDefinition`. What is _OpenApiReference Id_?

Comment: I don't have a simplified/isolated running example available, but as I recall it the name of the definition is the header (e.g. bearer) and the Id of the security reference matches the definition name.  Akin to what https://dev.to/eduardstefanescu/aspnet-core-swagger-documentation-with-bearer-authentication-40l6 writes.

Comment: That sems to be it, thank you: changed `c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2"` to `c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer"`. I'd call that a boobytrap.